# Migrate from ArcGIS 10.2 GDB to 10.0

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-10.2

I need to export data from an ArcGIS 10.2 File Geodatabase (GDB) to an older version, so that users running an older version can access the data. Similarly, I would like to save a .mxd file to an older version, ideally 10 or 10.1.

It seems that most people want to go the other direction. Has anyone found a way to do this with access to only a 10.2 license?

Comment: The file geodatabase format hasn't changed since 10.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Create File Geodatabase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Create_File_GDB/0017000000pw000000/) tool. Set desired version then import/export data from 10.2 geodatabase

In Arcmap, from the **File** menu, use **Save A Copy** to save the mxd to an older version.

Comment: Thanks. I feel silly for asking. I swear before I had done this under "Save as..." and no longer saw the option. Now I realize it is under "Save a Copy". Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I have 10.2 now and can confirm that a 10.2 MXD can be opened by 10.1 and that an GeoDatabase created in 10.2 can actually be accessed from 10.0 and 10.1.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the info. I had tried this on another machine and it was resulting in an error. It may be an unrelated issue on that system. Good to know that it is possible.